# WSL Ubuntu Directories are Read-Only on Windows 11

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, git-tower

Running WSL (Ubuntu Latest on Win 11).

Directories created in in linux are unreadable by applications launched in Windows.  For example, cloned some github projects in linux.  Tried editing files in my windows-based IDE (WebStorm) using the path "\wsl$\path\to\directory" and get "cannot save file" errors.  Tried opening the repo from my windows-based GIT IDE (Tower) using the path "\wsl$\path\to\directory" and it doesn't see the repo is in the directory, it prompts to create a new one.

If I use Explorer to navigate to the directory using "\wsl$\path\to\directory", right-click for properties, it says that the Attributes are 'Read-Only'.  If I try to uncheck and apply, it appears to be changing all the files, but if I recheck the properties after, its still 'Read-Only'.

Is this a Windows issue? Or a WSL/Linux issue?  Any ideas on resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a WSL directory to Tower currently only works after executing `git config --global --add safe.directory '*'`
The command should be executed in Windows, not in WSL.